# IsmSinkWriter expects keys to be written in strictly increasing order

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My DF job is failing on I believe `View.asSingleton()`, stage fails 4 times thus fails the whole job:

`(d373a0bb7c7bad6f): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IsmSinkWriter expects keys  to be written in strictly increasing order but was given RandomAccessData{buffer=[], size=0} as the previous key and RandomAccessData{buffer=[], size=0} as the current key. Expected 0 <= 0 at position 1. at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.IsmSink$IsmSinkWriter.commonPrefixLengthWithOrderCheck(IsmSink.java:209) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.IsmSink$IsmSinkWriter.add(IsmSink.java:166) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.IsmSink$IsmSinkWriter.add(IsmSink.java:85) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.process(WriteOperation.java:90) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:161) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnContext.outputWindowedValue(DoFnRunnerBase.java:288) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase$DoFnProcessContext.output(DoFnRunnerBase.java:450) at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.DataflowPipelineRunner$BatchViewAsSingleton$IsmRecordForSingularValuePerWindowDoFn.processElement(DataflowPipelineRunner.java:825)`

I'm trying to create a `PCollectionView` from `PCollection[CMS[String]]` - there is only single element in the collection (its size is about `3.75MiB`).

Help pls?

Update 1: Application failed when I reduced the size of the single element for the view to `1.88 MB` but was successful for `255.29 KB` (and smaller) - smells a bit like either some (un)documented limitation that I missed or a bug?

Comment: Are you certain there isn't more than one element in the PCollection?

Comment: Can you stick a Count.globally() in before View.asSingleton()? Yes, its strange when you decreased the size that it worked. Can you also share a job id of a failing and a succeeding job?

Comment: Pretty sure, cause: the logic is global `Combine.globally`, webui shows that there was only one element produced/consumed, also it works if I reduce the side of the element (without changes in logic - see update 1).

Comment: @LukaszCwik failed: `2016-05-09_16_57_33-2707902568290796198` (`1.88MB`) and `2016-05-09_15_36_01-9439192581708090524` (`3.75MB`) and "successful" (I cancelled it intentionally, once View succeeded) one `2016-05-09_17_08_00-3890636354877095934` (`255KB`).

Comment: I have created https://github.com/apache/incubator-beam/pull/317/files that should add a better user message about having multiple values. Even though you only have one value being written, more than one value maybe be being read. Can you try applying the changes to DataflowPipelineRunner.java locally and re-running your job?

Comment: @LukaszCwik Let me try this out - I still use `dataflowsdk`, will cross patch it, and try it out.

Comment: @LukaszCwik got a different error this time `java.lang.InstantiationError` - please see -> `2016-05-11_10_04_10-10576525664756415521`. Wonder if this is cause `dataflowsdk` and patch was for `beam` not sure about subtle differences.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111666/discussion-between-ravwojdyla-and-lukasz-cwik).

Comment: It seems as though your patching 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT and not the last 1.5.1 release: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/releases/tag/v1.5.1 either grap the src code or checkout from the specific tag/commit hash and then apply the code diff

Comment: That is correct - will go ahead and checkout tag `1.5.1` of dataflowsdk, apply the patch, compile and try again. Brb.

Comment: fyi - running now as `2016-05-11_13_11_50-6124239471917116048`

Comment: It seems like 2016-05-11_13_11_50-6124239471917116048 is running out of memory before it gets to View.asSingleton.

Comment: Yep, I'm already on highmem machines, will try smaller assurance for counting, I'm surprised tho - cause I did not see this previously for `2016-05-09_15_36_01-9439192581708090524` (the only difference afaik was DFSDK version `1.5.0`). New DF job: `2016-05-11_14_10_00-13495807892335849253`

Comment: @LukaszCwik again the same error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IsmSinkWriter expects keys to be written in strictly increasing order but was given RandomAccessData{buffer=[], size=0} as the previous key and RandomAccessData{buffer=[], size=0} as the current key. Expected 0 <= 0 at position 1. at ` for `2016-05-11_14_10_00-13495807892335849253` - note the size of the element is `3.76 MB`. I kinda believe it has to do something with the size, given that if I reduce the accuracy of my counting transform, thus reduce size of the final element, View transform is successful.

Comment: Also I think `2016-05-09_15_36_01-9439192581708090524` was also `1.5.1` so that memory issue is not related to the DF version or the patch.

Comment: I found the issue and it only impacts global window singletons which are greater than 1MB. Please use View.asIterable() or View.asList() as a workaround for now since it is not impacted and get the only element within the list/iterable when accessing it from within the DoFn.

Comment: Alright. Could you share what was the issue?

Comment: The global window is used as the key when creating the view. The global window serializes to 0 bytes and we put it into an index once a certain block size is surpassed. It turns out when we compare it to the last key (there was none in this case but we had a default of the 0 byte key) it errors. Fix is to use a representative saying that there was no prior key. It worked for smaller values because the block size was never surpassed.

Comment: Thanks - is this a fix in the SDK - is there a #ticket?

Comment: b/28715973 The fix is in the Dataflow worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 1.5.0 and 1.5.1 has this fixed now.

Globally windowed singletons in batch mode for 1.5.0 and 1.5.1 were impacted by a bug where they were unable to materialize a singleton greater than 1MB in size. Users were recommended to use View.asIterable() or View.asList() as a workaround since it was not impacted.